# Ubuntu 18.04 and Nvidia 340.107 drivers glitch

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, gpu-driver

So I'm using an older workstation Dell Precision 490 with the 3.0 dual core Xeon 4gb ram running a Quadro FX4600.  I dabble in Linux and know enough to be dangerous but am not fluent in command line shenanigans.  I installed the NVidia 340.107 drivers through the Software & Updates method. From what I've researched thats is correct and most up to date driver for my card.  After rebooting though I get some fascinating display art, glitches, text scrambling, etc.  Eventually the machine will lock up briefly, the screen will go blank for a few seconds, then come back on and everything appears to run smoothly from then on.  I've tried searching for the solution but other threads symptoms didn't appear to match my own.  Anyone able to explain whats going on, and how I could fix/prevent the start up glitch?

Answer (score 0):

I have artifacts on display too

Version driver: 340.107 from nvidia-340 (too)
Model video card: GeForce 210

But before install 18.04 i didn`t have these artifacts.
I think its bug in last version Nvidia derivers.